Does the Bruhat decomposition induces decomposition on integral points (on an open cell)?
Edit: both questions are resolved in comments. Let $F$ be a local field and $O$ its integral points. Let $G$ be a split reductive group over $O$. The Bruhat decomposition states that there is a decomposition
$$G(F)=\bigsqcup_{w \in W}B(F)wB(F)$$
where $B$ is borel subgroup of $G$.   It is not true that,
$$ G(O)=\bigsqcup_{w \in W}B(O)wB(O)$$
I am interested in the cell $N_{-}(F) B(F) \hookrightarrow G(F)$, where $N_-$ is the opposite unipotent of $B$. Is it true that
$$ G(O)\cap N_{-}(F)B(F)= N_-(O)B(O)?$$
As LSpice, explained this question seems to answer the question as false.

Despite my hasty (now-deleted) answer saying otherwise, doesn't the question you linked answer both parts negatively after all? For example, the only expression of $\begin{pmatrix} 1&\p&1\end{pmatrix} \in G(\mathbb Z_p)$ as an element of $U(\mathbb Q_p)\begin{pmatrix}&-1\1\end{pmatrix}B(\mathbb Q_p)$ is $\begin{pmatrix}1&p^{-1}\&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}&-1\1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}p&1\&p^{-1} \end{pmatrix}$.

yes, it is a typo. Thanks, that answers 1, but does it answer 2?

(I removed my reference to the typo. Sorry for my own inadvertent conflict wth your notation, using $U$ rather than $N_+$ for the unipotent radical.) Re, yes: the unique expression of $\begin{pmatrix}&1\-1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\p&1\end{pmatrix} \in G(\mathbb Z_p)$ as an element of $N_-(\mathbb Q_p)B(\mathbb Q_p)$ is $\begin{pmatrix}1\-p^{-1}&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}p&1\&p^{-1}\end{pmatrix}$.

Interesting counterexample — do you happen to know if it's true that $G(\mathbb Z_p) \cap N_-(\mathbb Q_p) N_+(\mathbb Q_p) = N_-(\mathbb Z_p) N_+(\mathbb Z_p)$ in general? Like if you cut the torus out of the picture? This at least appears to be true for $\mathrm{GL}_n$ (I think?).

@AshwinIyengar, re, I believe that that is true, but the proof that I have in mind would probably take more space than a comment box (reduce to $\operatorname{GL}_n$ easily, then some tiresome bookkeeping).  If you would like to ask it as a separate question, then I can try to answer it.

Thanks, I posted it here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/476088/intersection-of-integral-points-with-a-unipotent-and-its-opposite
